# How to copy a value from one position in data frame and apply it for the rest of the column(loop? apply?)?

Tags: r

I'm aware I didn't explain it well enough, so here's a screenshot on what I want to do. I realise I could easily do it in Excel, but i'd like to find out how to do it properly in R. I know what to do if the values are in the same row, but moving this row-wise got me befuddled.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to use `lead` here

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df1 %>%
   mutate(across(c(long, lat), ~ lead(., default = last(.)), 
           .names = '{col}to}'))
```

---

In `base R`, we can do

```
df1[c('longto', 'latto')] <- df1[c(2:nrow(df1), nrow(df1)), c('long', 'lat)]
```

Comment: Note that the values of `longto` and `latto` will be NA for the last record in your sample table. If this is an issue for you and you need their values to be equal to the preceding values (as in your example) you can add a final pass step where you do something like like `%>% mutate(across(c(long, lat), ~ if_else(is.na(.), lag(.), .))`

Comment: @bcarlsen i used `default = last(.)` so that the default option of `NA` is overrided with the last value

Comment: thank you! could you explain what _ ~ lead_ does exactly? and why is there a comma in the first argument? **~ lead(.**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data.frame(long=1:5,lat=1:5)
data <- data %>% mutate(
      longto = c(data$long[-1],data$long[nrow(data)]),
      latto = c(data$lat[-1],data$lat[nrow(data)])
)
```